# Notepad++ split line after given number of words

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in notepad++, to split one line text, to text with given maximum number of words in one line? I can do this with characters but not with words

Comment: Are you looking for `View` => `Word wrap`?

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics, alphanum, any character not space or punctuation? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression to add a new line after each 5 words:

- look for: `((\w+\W+){5})`
- replace to: `$1\n`

make sure to check "regular expression"

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fjpsYV/1).