# Notepad++ split line at variable characters preceding symbol

Tags: notepad++, sql, r

I am looking to split one line of data into a line for each state regarding a senate nomination vote. I have truncated all fifty states' data into two states' worth for the purposes of this question. I currently have the data in the following format:

```
Alabama: Sessions (R-AL), Yea Shelby (R-AL), Yea Alaska: Murkowski (R-AK), Nay Sullivan (R-AK), Yea
```

The problem here is that if I split the line at `:`, I wind up with

```
 Alabama:
 Sessions (R-AL), Yea Shelby (R-AL), Yea Alaska:
 Murkowski (R-AK), Nay Sullivan (R-AK), Yea NextState:
```

I also can't split at a fixed number of characters, since the states and senators have variable-length names.

What I'd like to be able to do is say "Find the `:` and split at the space before the preceding consecutive letter string."

This (hypothetically) would find the `:` and then count backwards "a-m-a-b-a-l-A", find the space, and split there.

That would look like

```
 Alabama: Sessions (R-AL), Yea Shelby (R-AL), Yea 
 Alaska: Murkowski (R-AK), Nay Sullivan (R-AK), Yea
```

Is this possible? Can you think of a better way? If not in Notepad++, how about R or SQL?

---

Update

---

I was able to use the split after x words from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1435269/notepad-split-line-after-given-number-of-words?rq=1) post where `((\w+\W+){9})` *ALMOST* does the trick, except for cases where a senator has two last names (i.e Cortez Masto, Van Hollen). You can download the .txt from my [OneDrive](https://livenwfsc-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/pylem_nwfsc_edu/ERG8Rx0GBulCg1BM4Q1188UBzPoX9Vf0BZFqoGSHJ3yB8A?e=nsNoPb).

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you split line with \r\n characters:

[image]

For Linux you split line with \n character:

[image]

And then click "Replace All"

Comment: FYI: the capture group is useless here and slow down the process, it's better to use `\S*` or in the specific case of the question: `\w+:` or `[a-zA-Z]+:`

Comment: @Nico - seems to work for single named states only and not for e.g. `South Carolina:`

Comment: It occurred to me last night that not only do I have a two-name senator problem, but also this two-name state problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a better solution, but if you don't need the clean-up often, you can get there in two steps.

Please make shure to copy your file before starting and try this quick and dirty solution using Notepad++.

(1) Clean up for one-name states:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\, (\w+) (\w+:)`
- Replace with: `\, $1\r\n$2`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

(2) Clean up for two-name states:

- Find what: `\, (\w+) (\w+) (\w+:)`
- Replace with: `\, $1\r\n$2 $3`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Please note the spaces.

[image]

Comment: This is great! I'll try this out when I get a chance.